# Problems with loading R6 object - R breaks

Tags: r, r6

I have a complex R6 object that gives me problems with R when I save and load it again. If I save it with saveRDS and loads it into another R session with readRDS, R starts printing random stuff to the console. E.g. after a load, I get something like this trying to exit R:

```
q()
   <environment: namespace:base>
  save
  status
  runLast
class
Save workspace image? [y/n/c]: n
   <environment: namespace:parallel>
  select
class
class
class
class
  [1]
x
  [2]
  [3]
class
class
```

As is clear the load totally screws up R. Simpler R6 object works fine, however I have still been unsuccesfull in finding which part of my object is causing this. Have anybody else seen this behavior before?

Answer (score 0):

The error turns out to be a buggy package, Prophet, which was used in the package which my R6 class was part of.